# Filtering on navigation properties for a set of value with toLowerCase

Tags: javascript, odata, jaydata

I have this JayData query (it can be checked at [JSLQ playground](http://jslq.spirit.de/)):

```
northwind.Products
  .filter( function( product ) {
    return  product.ProductName.toLowerCase() in ['tofu'];
  } )
  .toArray( function( products ) {
    console.dir( products );
  } );
```

For some unknown reasons this query produces incorrect filter expression:
[http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=(**tolowerProductName**%20eq%20%27tofu%27)&$callback=parent.handleJSONP_21&$format=json](http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?%24filter=%28%2a%2atolowerProductName%2a%2a%20eq%20%27tofu%27%29&%24callback=parent.handleJSONP_21&%24format=json)

I highlighted incorrect parameter with bold above.

So you can see that we have tolowerProductName, but it should be tolower(ProductName), so the right filter query should looks like this:
[http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=%28tolower%28ProductName%29%20eq%20%27tofu%27%29&$callback=parent.handleJSONP_21&$format=json](http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?%24filter=%28tolower%28ProductName%29%20eq%20%27tofu%27%29&%24callback=parent.handleJSONP_21&%24format=json)

Is anybody know a workaround?

Update:
Issue occurs only when I use toLowerCase with "in [array]", so for example this query is working just fine:

```
northwind.Products
  .filter( function( product ) {
    return  product.ProductName in ['Tofu'];
  } )
  .toArray( function( products ) {
    console.dir( products );
  } );
```

This query with toLowerCase is working just fine too:

```
northwind.Products
  .filter( function( product ) {
    return  product.ProductName.toLowerCase() == 'Tofu';
  } )
  .toArray( function( products ) {
    console.dir( products );
  } );
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that incorrect filter expression produces this line of code (for query with 'in' operator):

```
context.data = temp + context.data.replace(/\(/g, '').replace(/\)/g, '');
```

[Line 1542 in oDataProvider.js](https://github.com/jaydata/jaydata/blob/development/release/jaydataproviders/oDataProvider.js#L1542)

I replaced it with this code:

```
context.data = temp + context.data;
```

And now everything is working as expected. Maybe I introduced other issues with this fix, but at least it works as expected for my queries.

So the VisitSimpleBinaryExpression function looks like this now:

```
VisitSimpleBinaryExpression: function (expression, context) {
        context.data += "(";
        //TODO refactor!!!
        if (expression.nodeType == "in") {
            Guard.requireType("expression.right", expression.type, $data.Expressions.ConstantExpression);
            var paramValue = expression.right.value;
            if (!paramValue instanceof Array) { Guard.raise(new Exception("Right to the 'in' operator must be an array value")); }
            var result = null;
            var orResolution = { mapTo: "or", dataType: "boolean", name: "or" };
            var eqResolution = { mapTo: "eq", dataType: "boolean", name: "equal" };

            paramValue.forEach(function (item) {
                var idValue = item;
                var idCheck = Container.createSimpleBinaryExpression(expression.left, idValue,
                    $data.Expressions.ExpressionType.Equal, "==", "boolean", eqResolution);
                if (result) {
                    result = Container.createSimpleBinaryExpression(result, idCheck,
                    $data.Expressions.ExpressionType.Or, "||", "boolean", orResolution);
                } else {
                    result = idCheck;
                };
            });
            var temp = context.data;
            context.data = '';
            this.Visit(result, context);
            //context.data = temp + context.data.replace(/\(/g, '').replace(/\)/g, '');
            context.data = temp + context.data;
        } else {
            this.Visit(expression.left, context);
            context.data += " ";
            context.data += expression.resolution.mapTo;
            context.data += " ";
            this.Visit(expression.right, context);
        };
        context.data += ")";

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting that expression to a variable and then checking for that in ['tofu']?

Comment: it is working just fine without toLowerCase, e.g. 

northwind.Products
  .filter( function( product ) {
    return  product.ProductName in ['Tofu'];
  } )
  .toArray( function( products ) {
    console.dir( products );
  } );

Comment: Is product.ProductName a string? Have you tried wrapping product.ProductName.toLowerCase() in parens?

Comment: Can you show me an example on how to set the expression to a variable? Thank you!

Comment: var productName = product.ProductName.toLowerCase();

Comment: Then, return productName in ['tofu']

Comment: But, is that what you're trying to do? Shouldn't you be checking for tofu in product name?

Comment: hmm.. it looks like that I cannot do this in the filter expressions

Comment: return product.ProductName.toLowerCase().indexOf('tofu') ?

Comment: I used this query just for an example. I have this issue in the real project with a complex odata query. 

indexOf doesn't work for me and it looks like odata doesn't support indexof. so JayData produces this URL and it doesn't work - http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Products?$filter=indexof(tolower(ProductName),%27tofu%27)&$callback=parent.handleJSONP_24&$format=json

Comment: oh.. I see that indexof is working just fine:

return product.ProductName.toLowerCase().indexOf('tofu') > 0

Comment: let me check if I can replace "in ['tofu']" with "indexOf('tofu') > 0" in my real project

Comment: indexOf can be a workaround in some cases, but in my case I have a category, e.g. "Lorem" and a search query that may look like this: "Lorem 2007"

so this "Lorem".indexOf("Lorem 2007") > 0 is always false.

Comment: so in order to make it work as expected I need to split it by a whitespace and than use "Lorem".toLowerCase() in ['lorem', '2007']